# Looking for a better way to convert a list of text into json string using python3

Tags: python, json

Here is the input list (in file_id.txt):

```
file-F0Y6GbQ09k704jfGBQX0pgF8
file-FfYqQv00ypGfqQKkF96zX3yV
file-FfYqPf80ypGj712qFBggV2BV
file-FfQpFYQ0ypGqfjkJ8z90Ygzv
file-FfQpFYQ0ypGpQ4K7GGj40VVZ
file-FfQpFYQ0ypGxV3xG7BZQxz3y
file-FfQpFYQ0ypGZ3ZVk7745ZGFf
file-Ff0Qk100ypGYV26V52JZkJ0q
file-FfK1pZ80ypGjgyF73b3fFjgG
```

Here is the desired output (output.json) :

```
{
 "stage-xxx.input_files": [
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-F0Y6GbQ09k704jfGBQX0pgF8"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfYqQv00ypGfqQKkF96zX3yV"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfYqPf80ypGj712qFBggV2BV"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfQpFYQ0ypGqfjkJ8z90Ygzv"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfQpFYQ0ypGpQ4K7GGj40VVZ"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfQpFYQ0ypGxV3xG7BZQxz3y"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfQpFYQ0ypGZ3ZVk7745ZGFf"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-Ff0Qk100ypGYV26V52JZkJ0q"},
  {"$dnanexus_link": "file-FfK1pZ80ypGjgyF73b3fFjgG"}
 ]
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 env
fname = input("Enter file name of the list: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "file_id.txt"

stage_name = input("Enter stage name for the input: ")
if len(stage_name) < 1 : stage_name = "stage-xxx"

input_var = input("Enter input variable name: ")
if len(input_var) < 1 : input_var = "input_files"

fh = open(fname)

out_file = open('output.json', 'w')
out_file.write('{\n "' + f'{stage_name}' + "." + f'{input_var}' + '": [' + "\n")
for line in fh:
    fileid = line.rstrip()
    out_file.write("  {" + "\"$dnanexus_link\": " + f'"{fileid}"' + "},\n")
out_file.write(' ]\n}\n')
out_file.close()
print("output.json created!")
```

I am fairly new to python and not sure how to remove the comma at the end of last file in the output json. And I was wondering if there is a way to use the json module to dump the file list into json format without the static text coding..

Comment: I would suggest creating a `dict` and converting that to json using the `json` library that comes with python.

Comment: Thanks. That is a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads your file making the `list` of `dict`s as it goes.

I then wrap this `list` in the final `dict` and use json.dumps() to get a string:

```
import json

with open('file_id.txt') as f:
    txt = [{'$dnanexus_link': line.strip()} for line in f]

#print(txt)

d = {'stage-xxx.input_files': txt}
print(json.dumps(d))
```

Output as your `output.json` but on one line.